# Как понять, в какой строке отлаживаемой dll выброшено исключение?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, библиотеки

Отлаживаю dll в работе, присоединяясь отладчиком к вызывающему её процессу. После прохода очередной точки останова и нажатия кнопки "Продолжить выполнение" выбрасывается исключение:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00007ffbf26c9e24 in <имя исп. файла>.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000003480ef0.
```

Есть ли возможность как-то локализовать место в коде, откуда было выброшено это исключение?

P.S. Dll-ка объёмная, многопоточная, с использованием сторонних (не мной написанных) библиотек. Отчасти из-за этого не имею возможности прикрепить код. Минимальный воспроизводимый пример в данном случае тоже составить невозможно, т.к. для этого воспроизводящему будет необходимо запустить процесс, использующий данную dll.

Пользуюсь VS 2008 SP1. На другие IDE или более новую версию этой перейти не могу. Требование заказчика.

Comment: дллка ваша или чья-то? если она собрана без отладочной информации, то вы номер строки, в которой произошло исключение не отловите. Если есть исходный код, то соберите ее с отладочной информацией. добавьте try{} catch() в тех местах где потенциально может быть исключение, и тогда в ex.toString() у вас будет полный путь к файлу и номер строки где исключение было словлено.

Comment: @Yakov, dll-ка моя, исходники есть, но в том и дело, что я понятия не имею, где именно может теоретически возникнуть это исключение, а объём кода слишком велик, чтобы оборачивать в try-catch каждый метод, например.

Comment: P.S. у меня была похожая проблема бывал сбой в DLL без исходников который шел вместе с SDK к считывателям FEIG, причем этот сбой бывал иногда, скажем один за в день, но он уносил с собой в могилу весь процесс к которому эта длл была подгружена. я решил эту проблему так - весь код работы с длл обернул в хттп-запрос внутри службы, а приложение уже его запускало запросом к этой службе, в свойствах службы был выбран перезапуск при сбое. работает уже много лет отлично.

Comment: @Yakov к сожалению, у меня сбой стабильный, постоянно при одних и тех же действиях, но какая часть кода может к нему привести, не ясно.

Comment: если есть исходники, тогда при возникновении исключения должен быть трейс в отладчике если код собран с отладочной информацией. смотри настройки исключений в иде. может что-то выключено.

Comment: @Yakov можно поподробнее про настройки исключений? Куда копать?

Comment: опять же для отладки можешь использовать более свежую иде чтобы найти место где сбоит, а потом перенести код обратно в старый проект.

Comment: Под отладчиком при выбрасывании таких исключений автоматически должна срабатывать точка останова в месте возникновения. Проверьте настройки отладки исключений в окошке Exceptions. @Yakov Access violation не является C++ исключением и не перехватывается try-catch, а совет добавлять try-catch для отладки и смотреть ex.toString(), мало того, что сам по себе трешовый, так еще и говорит о том, что вы перепуталили язык.

Comment: да не обратил внимание что стоит тег с++. можно попробовать включить перехват исключений в доп. опциях компилятора и использовать не стандартные __try/__except. По опыту с множеством потоков и исключениями могу сказать, что чаще всего они происходят из-за того, что поток обращается к данным которые уже были освобождены. либо поток не останавливается вовремя, без анализа кода трудно сказать где именно так может происходить,  к примеру так было, т.к. я не вызывал thread.join() в основном потоке приложения, опасаясь заблокировать основной поток. при этом не дожидался его остановки и делал delete

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414027/visual-c-unmanaged-code-use-eha-or-ehsc-for-c-exceptions тут вроде объяснено как можно отловить исключение типа ошибки доступа к памяти, и почему так делать не стоит тоже разжевали. но в целях поиска места возникновения исключения я думаю это может сработать.